# redirect Createview to Updateview if record exist in 1:1

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to redirect a logged in user to an `Updateview` instead of a `Createview` if they have already created a record in the `organizations` model. 
My `organizations` has a 1:1 relationship with my `users` model.

I am currently able to return the `Updateview` with the `get` method if the related record exists, but the Url is not redirected to `/update`

My code:

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("add/", view=organization_add_view, name="add"),
    path("update/", view=organization_update_view, name="update"),
    path("<int:id>/<str:slug>", view=organization_detail_view, name="detail"),
]
```

**models.py**

```py
class Organization(TimeStampedModel):

    name = CharField(_("Organization Name"), blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), max_length=100, unique=False, populate_from=('name',))
    user = OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```py
class OrganizationDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Organization
    slug_field = "slug"
    slug_url_kwarg = "slug"

organization_detail_view = OrganizationDetailView.as_view()


class OrganizationAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Organization
    form_class = OrganizationForm

    success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return self.get_success_url()

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(OrganizationAddView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            'user': self.request.user,
            'is_update': False
        }


    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
            return redirect("organizations:update")
        else:
            return super(OrganizationAddView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("organizations:list")

organization_add_view = OrganizationAddView.as_view()


class OrganizationUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Organization
    form_class = OrganizationForm
    success_message = 'Organization updated successfully.'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return obj

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            'is_update': True
        }

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists():
            return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect("organizations:add")

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(OrganizationUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("organizations:update")

organization_update_view = OrganizationUpdateView.as_view()
```

**forms.py**

```py
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")

        super(OrganizationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        organization = kwargs.get('instance')

        user = self.request.user

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        if organization:
            if organization.email is None:
                self.initial['email'] = self.request.user.email
        elif user.email:
            self.initial['email'] = user.email

        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

        submit_btn_text = 'Continue'

        if kwargs.get('initial')['is_update']:
            submit_btn_text = 'Update'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', submit_btn_text)) 

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 10, 'cols': 60}),
            # 'logo': forms.ImageField()
        }
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['created', 'expires', 'is_sponsor', 'view_count', 'user']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect rather than calling the view directly.

```
    if self.model.objects.get(user=self.request.user):
        return redirect("organisations:update")
     else:
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: When I use the above code, and organization does not exist, it goes into an infinite loop, which kind of makes sense. So what should the `else` condition look like? Im correct in that it should all go in the `get` method of `OrganizationAddView`?

Comment: You should call the super class get method, see the edit.

Comment: So this works well to redirect, but on adding a new record I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`. I updated my code and added in `forms.py`

Comment: I should also add that the record does get added, even with the error.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is that you are `return`ing the update view, when you should be `redirect`ing to it. Returning an [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) that points to the Update URL will give you exactly what you want.  Just make sure to pass the `pk` of the relevant organization through to the redirect url.